# Title page format

Tags: titles

I'm using `\documentclass{report}`

On the `\titlepage`, how can I write the `\author` and the `\date` section in the down-left corner?

Thank you!

Comment: There are `\maketitle` (that print `\title` and `\author` automatically in a fixed format) and  `\begin{titlepage} whatever you want in free format  \end{titlepage}`. In this case seems that you need the second approach, but it is not clear in your question.

Comment: OK, so I cannot have either \author, \date or \title in a free format?

Comment: There are tricks to extract  `\author`,`\date` and `\title` in any place of the document, including the title page, and to change `\maketitle` format, but if you need this information only in the title page with your own format, it is unnecessary mess.

Comment: You also can take a look at the `titling` package, which provides tools to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill

  \begin{center}

  {\Huge My Title}
  \vskip 2cm

  {\Large Subtitle or whatever}
  \vskip 1cm

  {\large Institution or whatever}
  \end{center}

\vfill
\vfill

\begin{tabular}{r}
Author Name\\
\small\today\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```